# ¿Cómo se puede descargar una imagen que no tiene extensión del archivo con php?

Tags: php, curl

Quiero descargar una imagen con php pero no tiene la extensión del archivo, en cambio tiene una id (https://4promotional.net:9090/WsEstrategia/imagesWeb/imagen?id=12 OZ) al querer descargar la imagen me envía error o un archivo dañado.
Agrego el fragmentó de código.

```
if (true) {
    // Client
    $ch = curl_init('https://4promotional.net:9090/WsEstrategia/imagesWeb/imagenExtra?id=12 OZ');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOSIGNAL, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS, 200);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    $curl_errno = curl_errno($ch);
    $curl_error = curl_error($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    if ($curl_errno > 0) {
            echo "cURL Error ($curl_errno): $curl_error\n";
    } else {
            echo "Data received: $data\n";
    }
} else {
        // Server
        sleep(10);
        echo "Done";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Parece ser que la cuestión está en el espacio que no reconoce como un caracter válido, lo puedes [reemplazar con %20](https://www.google.com/search?q=url+spaces+%2520). Adicional no necesitas la linea `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS, 200);` porque cierra la conexión con el servidor en 0.2 segundos.

De esta forma tuve respuesta del servidor, notar el `%20` en la url:

```
$ch = curl_init('https://4promotional.net:9090/WsEstrategia/imagesWeb/imagenExtra?id=12%20OZ');
// ### Agregué esta linea para que no me rechazara el servidor, si te funciona sin ella, la puedes omitir.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); 
// ###
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOSIGNAL, 1);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS, 200); // <- Esto cierra la conexión antes de que termine
$data = curl_exec($ch);
$curl_errno = curl_errno($ch);
$curl_error = curl_error($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Efectivamente, la URL que le pasas a curl tiene que estar codificada como URL, por tanto el espacio tiene que reemplazarse por `%20`